# Changing range of natural breaks QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile of population points, which I've categorized to show the difference in size for each point. However, I'm not satisfied with the range of values it has set out (in picture below).
Would there be a way to exclude values of 0 so that it starts at 0.1 up to 1 instead of 11? And so on for the rest of the points?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you double click on the category you want to change you get a popup window that lets you change the lower and upper bounds of the class.

[image]